# How can I logout user on route change once JWT token is expired?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, routes, jwt

I'm using Passport JWT and I want to check JWT token validity to perform a logout if it's already expired. I already made it work on page refresh but not on route change (from navbar, for example). I need to find a way to check it every time **any** route component is re-rendered, and I know it's very likely that I don't need to do it on every single component. I just don't know *how*.

Here's the code that's working for page refresh:

On Express

**authenticated.js**

```
router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
    if (!user) {
      res.status(401);
      res.send("Unauthorized")
    }
  })(req, res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

On React

**AuthContext.js**

```
export const AuthContext = createContext();

function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = usePersistedState(false, "loaded");
  const [user, setUser] = usePersistedState(null, "username");
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = usePersistedState(
    false,
    "auth"
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/authenticated")
      .then((response) => {
        return;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setUser("");
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
        setIsLoaded(true);
      });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {!isLoaded ? (
        <h3>Loading...</h3>
      ) : (
        <AuthContext.Provider
          value={{ user, setUser, isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated }}
        >
          {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default AuthProvider;
```

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <AuthProvider>
    <App />
  </AuthProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to get it done by adding this `useEffect` function on my `PrivateOutlet.js`, which handles the private routes, but it didn't work:

```
function PrivateOutlet() {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/authenticated")
      .then((response) => {
        return;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        authContext.setIsAuthenticated(false);
        authContext.setUser("");
      });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [location]);

  return authContext.isAuthenticated ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ path: location.pathname }} />
  );
}

export default PrivateOutlet;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach listed on the "update" section from the original question was on the right path, however there was some caveats on my code preventing it to work properly.

I forgot to remove the `useEffect()` from `AuthContext.js` after moving it to `PrivateOutlet.js`, and I also modified the dependency array to include `location.pathname` instead of just `location`:

**PrivateOutlet.js**

```
function PrivateOutlet() {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/authenticated")
      .then((response) => {
        return;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        authContext.setIsAuthenticated(false);
        authContext.setUser("");
      });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [location.pathname]);

  return authContext.isAuthenticated ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ path: location.pathname }} />
  );
}

export default PrivateOutlet;
```

This was a minor change and probably didn't interfere at all on anything, but in `authenticated.js` on my Express server I just moved back from using a custom callback to the standard Passport callback, allowing it to handle unauthorized calls by itself:

**authenticated.js**

```
router
  .route("/")
  .get(passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    //do some stuff
    res.json();
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is not specific to any platform/language. In general, the authentication provider/service is issuing the token to the client. The token meant for accessing the private resoruces upon validating by resouce server. As you're using the `JWT token`, so a resouce server/service can validate the token without talking to authentication service or without performing a database look-up. Your server side code always need to validate the token with the incoming requests, which you can do by creating an interceptor for protected requests. In short, you can invoke call from client to validate the token whenever required.

Comment: I've edited the original question, since I made some progress on it and also to make it more objective.

Answer (score 0):

it could be a socket call for the checking through a wrapper component. If the socket returns false, then history.push him into a page where the login is not required